# Automating the editing of a specific git commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

Lately I find myself doing a lot of `git rebase -i <commit_hash>^`, replace the first 'pick' with an 'e', make the changes I want to the commit, and `git rebase --continue`.

I was wondering if I could make an alias to automate this process, but I fail to imagine how exactly. Is it possible to send the todo to a shell script, instead of the editor?

The intended result: running `git edit <commit_hash>` would do the process described above (except for the `git rebase --continue`), but without the need of me manually choosing the first commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+interactive+non-interactive

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+interactive+automatic

Comment: This is it, here's the command I ended up aliasing for future reference:
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="gsed -i '0,/pick/s//e/'" git rebase -i ${1}^

(gsed because I'm on mac)